# How to push values into array in my example?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to add 6 days of a week to my week array and was wondering the best way to do this.

I have something like

```
var week = [];
//monday is monday time I calculate eariler
week.push(monday.setDate(monday.getDate()));

for (var i = 0; i<=4; i++) {
    var day = monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1);
    week.push(day);
}
```

I push my day 1 outside of for loop and push the rest of the day in the loop. I feel like the codes can be improved. Does anyone have ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: loop is adding same values each time  in array. Add day variable outside the loop

Comment: but... why you want an array with 6 equal days and why only 6 ?

Answer (score 1):

The best improvement I can see is to put it all in one loop:

This should help:

```
var week = [];
for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    var day = monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1);
    week.push(day);
}
```

Or even more compressed, though arguably less readable:

```
var week = [];
for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    week.push(monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1));
}
```

EDIT: Corrected above code to reflect proper incrementing of the date.

EDIT: Thanks to Dwza for the correction!

Comment: @Dwza Instead of executing the call, then joining a loop to execute the same call, it is compressed into a single loop.  The OP was asking for improvement and that's what I saw could be improved. :)

Comment: I know, I just was wondering because in you post, "for improvements" stands some with "(causing issues)". Actually there is no issue :)

Comment: @Dwza Actually excellent point!  I misread the initial going into 0 with the next going into 0 b/c of the loop, but that is an incorrect assumption.  I will correct.  Thank you!